# What is the replacement of DefualtChannelFuture in Netty 4

Tags: netty, netty4

In Netty 3 there is the [DefualtChannelFuture](https://netty.io/3.9/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html) class.

It is used to create an instance of `ChannelFuture`. What would the replacement be in Netty 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `Channel.newPromise()` or `ChannelHandlerContext.newPromise()`if you need to create an own instance of a `ChannelPromise`. A `ChannelPromise` is a sub-type of `ChannelFuture`.